# DLL load failed: initialization of a DLL file failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, cython, importerror

I get the following message

"DLL load failed: initialization of a DLL file failed"

when I try to import my module helloworld.pyd in a Python script. This file was generated by running this setup file

"""setup.py"""

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
   ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)

from the command prompt with

python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Here helloworld.pyx is a pyx-file that contains

```
print "Hello World"
```

I use Python 7.2.1 (64-bit) and Cython version 0.14.1

My operative system is Windows 7 (64 bit)

I would be grateful for all the help that I can get!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I got the same one, also on Win7 64Bit.

Comment: No I haven't resolved it yet, but I think it might work if Cython is upgraded to a 64 bit version. I haven't been able to try this yet though

Comment: I have the Anaconda package 64 bit. I assume Cython to be 64bit as well. But how to check? Initially it worked, though, just after a while of coding it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I am experience the same issue here....any luck?